# OneAPI installation Failed

Tags: intel, failed-installation, intel-oneapi

I have Visual studio 2019 and 2022 installed with Intel OneAPI toolkit previously. It installed and worked flawlessly before. When I tried to install a newer version, I've got following error message.

Removal of component failed.
Component id: intel.oneapi.win.spcpp_st.vs2022, name:intel DPC++ Compatibility Tool, version 2022.0.0-97.
Error: Sequence execution failed.

Although I tried to repair, uninstall and etc., nothing worked.
Intel support and forums are kind of hopeless. I can't even search oneAPI in those avenues.
Appreciate any kudos.

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be much easier:

1. Choose custom installation.
2. Then uncheck VS 2019 on the step of VS integration.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the same problem described here
tried and it worked
https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/Update-and-uninstall-of-OneAPI-Toolkits-fails/td-p/1367069

[image]

[image]